# How do I install NumPy in GIMP in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, numpy, gimp

I'm trying to install NumPy, so that I can use it in Python plug-ins for GIMP. Every time I try, it installs into the external Python, and the Python inside GIMP can't find it. How do I install NumPy, so that GIMP can find it?

Comment: What OS are you on? (This matters.)

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12699#issuecomment-453354622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the flatpak version, you can install `numpy` as a "user" package using your "general" `pip` installer (and not the `apt` kind) and it will be taken in account by Gimp's built-in runtime (just tested, it works). You may have to force a specific version to get a V2-compatible `numpy`:

```
pip install --user -I numpy==1.11.0
```

I cannot tell you how to install `pip` for your V2 python on 20.04. On my 19.04 `apt install python-pip` did the trick but on 20.04 it could be `apt install python2-pip` or you would have to install it by hand.

Comment: None of that worked. What version of Ubuntu and GIMP should I revert to to make this work?

Comment: What version of Gimp are you using? Flatpak? AppImage? Did you install Python v2 and corresponding Pip on your Ubuntu?  Tested my answers using 2.10.8 flatpak on an Ubuntu 16.04. On my Ubuntu 19.10 I have a regular 2.10.14 installed from a PPA, and a 2.10.18 I compiled from source).

Comment: After I followed the instructions at this site: [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/), Your steps worked. Thanks.

Comment: While we are a it: https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gimp-python-and-numpy